# what exactly does Annotations do in python programming language?

Tags: python, python-3.x, annotations

I am completely confused about the use of annotation in python...

In python documentation it says that Function annotations are completely optional metadata information....you can refer to https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html

and if it is completely optional then why are we having this in python?

Comment: actually the answer for annotations provided on stackoverflow are for java...I want the answer for python...please provide some examples and their respective explanations.....

Comment: Out of the three links that I gave you, only one even *mentions* Java.  They are all three about Python.

Answer (score 1):

In the [PEP 3107](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3107/#fundamentals-of-function-annotations) related to these annotations, you can read:

> The only way that annotations take on meaning is when they are interpreted by third-party libraries. These annotation consumers can do anything they want with a function's annotations.

You can use it for documentation purposes, linting, validation... But nothing in the standard library use it.

Answer (score 0):

Functions annotations can be truly great when using a library, it helps you knowing the type of the parameters you need to send without having to crawl into tons of documentation sheets.